# simultaneous equations with irrational variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

Solve the simultaneous equations $a\sqrt a+b\sqrt b=183$ and $a\sqrt b+b\sqrt a=182$
I made an attempt in vain to equate the coefficients and eliminate

Answer (score 1):

We know the values for two symmetric polynomial expressions in $x=\sqrt a$ and $y=\sqrt b$. These can be expressed in the *elemntary* symmetric polynomials$s=x+y$ and $p=xy$.
If we have $s$ and $p$, we find $x,y$ as the roots of $X^2-pX+s$.

Now $$\begin{align}a\sqrt a+b\sqrt b&=x^3+y^3\\
&=(x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)\\&=s^3-3sp\end{align}$$
and 
$$\begin{align}a\sqrt b+b\sqrt a&=x^2y+y^2x\\
&=xy(x+y)\\&=ps\end{align}$$
We conclude that $s=\sqrt[3]{183+3\cdot 182}$ and then $p=\frac{182}s$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Take $x = \sqrt a$, $y = \sqrt b$ and note that $(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3(x^2y+xy^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

-Take eq 1;
-square both sides;
-take eq 2;
-square both sides;
-use the formula 
   (a+b)^3 = a^3+ b^3 +3(a^2 b+a b^2)
-once you have equated that you get;
   (a+b)^3 = 132861
-taking 3root. you get
   a+b = 51.